# How to ensure an Ajax Call completes before submitting form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I have the following project I'm working on. It starts out with a quiz that's wrapped in a form, each question of the quiz has a specific response that needs to be displayed depending on the users answer. Once the quiz is submitted, an ajax call is made that takes in the answers and assigns variables for the correct responses. These responses, along with some other posted data from the quiz, is sent to a page that dynamically builds and emails a PDF based on the answers.

The problem I have is sometimes the ajax call doesn't work. The PDF is still generated and emailed, and all the normal post data from the quiz is still there, but it's missing all the ajax variables. I figured out this was initially happening because the PDF page was loading before the Ajax call had finished. I put an alert(); after the ajax call and this seemed to fix it most of the time, but there is still instances where it returns a PDF missing the values.

So, my question is, what is a better way to go about ensuring that the ajax call is finished before I move onto the PDF generation page? I still need it to have the form submitted, as there are some posted variables that aren't sent in ajax. I've tried several things, from the alert, to having a timeout of several seconds as the callback function, to my current try listed below.

The submit button:

```
 <input class="sg-button sg-submit-button" id="sg_SubmitButton" onclick="set_session()" type="submit"
```

Ajax Call:

```
function set_session()
{

    event.preventDefault();
    names = [];
    text = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function() 
        {
    names.push($(this).attr("value"));
        });

    $('input:checked').each(function() 
        {
    text.push($(this).attr("title"));
        });


    question_one_val = names[0];
    question_one_text = text[0];
    question_two_val = names[1];
    question_two_text = text[1];
    question_three_val = names[2];
    question_three_text = text[2];
    question_four_val = names[3];
    question_four_text = text[3];
    question_five_val = names[4];
    question_five_text = text[4];
    question_six_val = names[5];
    question_six_text = text[5];
    question_seven_val = names[6];
    question_seven_text = text[6];
    question_eight_val = names[7];
    question_eight_text = text[7];
    question_nine_val = names[8];
    question_nine_text = text[8];
    question_ten_val = names[9];
    question_ten_text = text[9];
    question_eleven_val = names[10];
    question_eleven_text = text[10];
    question_twelve_val = names[11];
    question_twelve_text = text[11];
    question_thirteen_val = names[12];
    question_thirteen_text = text[12];
    name_val = $('.name_val').val();
 $.post("ajax_request.php", 
    {first_question: question_one_val,
     first_question_text: question_one_text,
     second_question: question_two_val,
     second_question_text: question_two_text,
     third_question: question_three_val,
     third_question_text: question_three_text,
     fourth_question: question_four_val,
     fourth_question_text: question_four_text,
     fifth_question: question_five_val,
     fifth_question_text: question_five_text,
     sixth_question: question_six_val,
     sixth_question_text: question_six_text,
     seventh_question: question_seven_val,
     seventh_question_text: question_seven_text,
     eighth_question: question_eight_val,
     eighth_question_text: question_eight_text,
     ninth_question: question_nine_val,
     ninth_question_text: question_nine_text,
     tenth_question: question_ten_val,
     tenth_question_text: question_ten_text,
     eleventh_question: question_eleven_val,
     eleventh_question_text: question_eleven_text,
     twelveth_question: question_twelve_val,
     twelveth_question_text: question_twelve_text,
     thirteenth_question: question_thirteen_val,
     thirteenth_question_text: question_thirteen_text,
      success: function(){


      $('#sg_FormFor1557763').submit()

  }

    });








}
```

Then here is were the ajax is processed. I'm only going to include a small sample as it does the same thing for all cases.

```
$test = $_POST['first_question'];
$test = question_one($test);
$_SESSION['question_one']=$test;

 function question_one($test)
    {
        $question_one_response_a = "Response for A";
$question_one_response_b = "Response for B";
$question_one_response_c = "Response for C";
$question_one_response_d = "Response for D";
$question_one_response_e = "Response for E";



        $question_one_response="test";
        if ($test == "a")
            {
                $question_one_response = $question_one_response_a;
            }
        elseif($test == "b")
            {
                $question_one_response = $question_one_response_b;
            }

        elseif($test == "c")
            {
                $question_one_response = $question_one_response_c;
            }

        elseif($test == "d")
            {
                $question_one_response = $question_one_response_d;
            }

        elseif($test == "e")
            {
                $question_one_response = $question_one_response_e;
            }
        else 
        {
            $question_one_response = "your getting an error";
        }
            return $question_one_response;
    }
```

Now the code seems to be correct for the most part, as it does work, but not every time. I would say it's about 50/50 on whether it works, and I can not figure out why?

Comment: Why do you make 2 requests? There is no user-interaction between the two so you can do everything in one request (your ajax call for example). And your `$.post()` function does not look correct, is that the real code?

Comment: The two post requests were for convenience really, some of the data didn't need anything done to it (for example the name) so I didn't bother sending it through the ajax function. Yes, that is the real code.

Comment: I'd do everything in one request, but see my answer concerning the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the following **pseudo code** outlines:

```
function handle_form_submission(e) {
    // Do whatever needs to be done
};

$('form#myform').submit(handle_form_submission);

function send_stuff_via_ajax() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'server_side_script.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            // Whatever you wish to send to the server
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 'all_good') {
                // Everything is cool, submit the form
                $('form#myform').submit();
            } else {
                // Try the ajax again
                send_stuff_via_ajax();

                // Warning this could result in an infinite look without some limiter
            }
        },
        error: function(result) {
            // Also try again
            send_stuff_via_ajax();
        }
    });

}
```

$("button#send_stuff_via_ajax").click(send_stuff_via_ajax);

The critical bit here is that you can use `submit()` not just to set a handler function but also to actually trigger a submit. The same thing would work with `click()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1- Move the set_session to the form element
    `<form onSubmit="return set_session();" >`
2- Next Change the set_session method to be and redirect
    `...`
    `$.post(<url>, {data}, function(data) {`
        `window.location.replace("https://path_to_pdf_file");`
    `}`

`return false;`

It is important to return `false` to the onSubmit call

Answer (score 0):

The data section of your `$.post()` function looks wrong:

```
   $.post("ajax_request.php", {
     first_question: question_one_val,
     // ...
     thirteenth_question_text: question_thirteen_text,
     success: function(){
       $('#sg_FormFor1557763').submit()    
      }
   });
```

You are sending your success function as a parameter in the data section instead of putting it as a third parameter to the post function. That probably causes your problem.

You should change it to:

```
   $.post(
     "ajax_request.php",
     {
       first_question: question_one_val,
       // ...
       thirteenth_question_text: question_thirteen_text
     },
     // The third parameter is your callback function that is executed if the request succeeds
     function() {
       $('#sg_FormFor1557763').submit();
     }
   });
```

Although it probably does not make a difference, you can also remove the inline click hander `onclick="set_session()"` and replace the name of your function with something like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  // the contents of your function
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work, I'm still getting back blank PDFs. I'm guessing maybe it has something to with how the PDF is generated?